# Slow Viewport in Big Scene

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I recently am working on a scene in Blender Cycles which has a relatively great number of objects. Some are more detailed and need more subdivide but the small objects are all just subdivided once. 
So the problem is that my blender gets slow when I move the camera in the viewport. 
In 3ds Max you can choose objects that you dont need to look at right now and select "Show them as box", which will let them be displayed as a wireframe box and therefore wont stress the scene that much.

My question is if there is a function like that in Blender? (exept hiding objects)

And do you have tips on working on bigger scenes in blender too keep it fast? For example I have a lot of chopsticks in my scene. Should I merge them together to 1 object instead of individual objects and then just give them different materials?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Regarding the second question generally you should keep only one question per question and explain everything in more details, it's not entirely clear what's exactly the problem. 2000 objects in the scene will be slower than 1 object with 200 meshes so you can adjust according to that

Comment: Yeah its similiar. Should i delete my question now?

Comment: It's your solution but I don't think you should. The wording in your question can help someone else to find that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change how your object is drawn by changing the "Draw Type" in Properties panel -> object -> display.

To my experience, less objects you have in your scene better blender run, so it's a good idea to merge them in 1 object.